# Explain "ConnectionStrings" in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am totally new to .NET VB, I have this code in Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="myDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=storage\webdb;Initial Catalog=myWebDB;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I want to know where is the database saved? how can I edit my database directly?

Comment: See MSDN about [SqlConnection.ConnectionString property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) and in particular the Data Source key/value or for a more general docs [ConnectionStrings explained](https://www.connectionstrings.com/connection-strings-explained/)

Comment: Thanks, but in the code above I didn't know what does `storage\webdb` is, is it a directory folder? or a web address? or is it a value identified somewhere else?

Comment: It should be the name of a host server on your lan network (storage) followed by the name of an instance of sql server installed on that pc (webdb). Usually you don't have to specify the instance name but that's depends on how the Sql Server engine has been installed in that server